# Regular Expression to parse a string from end until a delimiter is reached(Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I need a regular expression to parse a text  The directory is
/home/foo/bar/hello.txt.
I would like to get the hello.txt and get rid of the rest of the directory, so i would like to delete home/foo/bar/ and only get the hello.txt

Comment: Why do you want it? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's a better way to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use links because im actually working with directories in perl, I want to parse a filename from a directory.

Comment: Oh, man. That's just the very different question. Please consider asking question about what you actually want and don't invent something different from that. See update in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update: should work for paths as well :-)

```
my ($filename) = $dir =~ m!^.*/(.*)!;
```

or

```
my $filename = (split '/', $dir)[-1];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do things like that it means that you're using a wrong approach to construct your URIs. You don't need to parse things you construct, you need to have a schema for your URIs.

**Update:** For files in a filesystem, use [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Basename)

Comment: Well the way i wrote it, I never visit actually visit,so it would be difficult to get the request URI

Comment: Edited my problem according to my needs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following equivalent regexes :

```
 my ($extract1) = m { ( [^/]* ) $ }x ;
```

and with comments added

```
 my ($extract2) = m {  
     (           # start capturing
       [^/] *    # anything other than / repeated
     )           # start capturing      
     $           # anchor to end of string  
  }x  ;
```

if you add the **x** at the end then you can add white space and comments to help explain the regex.